# Emgu CV capture class does not exist

Tags: c#, opencv, dll, emgucv

So I recently wanted to make a face detecting winform(don't judge) for a test  of emguCV, and installed the latest version of emguCV(3.4.1.2976) and read some tutorials on how to import on the emguCV wiki, but there are way less DLL's - instead of openCV and emguCV things there are only like 4. so I imported them and set to always copy to working directory, and I had some of the functionality, but when I tried to do a video capture straight from the tutorial from the wiki that is called video capture in  7 lines, it said that Capture does not exist and I have to make it. Then I downgraded emgucv to 2.4.2.1777 and imported all the dlls, this time there was way more. It all worked in visual studio and when I did the 7 line capture tutorial it was all working, until I hit run, where I got: "System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.'
"
and then I read that I have to import the DLL'S to the working dir(already done that :| )
and then I found that I have to run in x86, but that didn't help... I have been struggling like this for a couple of hours. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I am following all the tutorials :|. Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at a tutorial from 2009, it is a bit old an outdated. Along the way the Capture class was replaced with the VideoCapture class. So make that change, reference the EmguCV files and copy either the x64 or x86 folder to your bin\Debug folder (for x86) or you bin\x64\Debug folder for x64 and it should run.
A complete working example can be downloaded from [here](https://cloud.rs-us.net/index.php/s/Zykpu9NOyZuYagW)

Hope this helps,
Doug

Comment: download the nuget for emgu.cv and the windows runtime http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation